# Nameserver A records in Microsoft DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, windows-dns

I think I understand that in DNS a given zone must return its own nameservers (as NS records) in order that intermediary DNS servers are able to then query information directly about that domain.

However, looking at the configuration file in Microsoft DNS, I see:

```
;
;  Zone NS records
;
@                       NS  ns1.mydomain.com.
ns1.mydomain.com.       A   x.x.x.x
@                       NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
ns2.mydomain.com.       A   x.x.x.x
```

My question is, why are there A records added for the nameservers? Does this mean that if I change the IP address of my nameserver, I need to ensure that every domain pointing at that nameserver is updated with the new IP address?

Or are these A records updated automatically by the DNS software upon a change?

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the ip address  of the name servers, you only need to edit the A entry(ip address) in the DNS zone of the domain to reflect the change and for proper resolving of all domains registered with that name servers.

for instance, if the name servers are ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com, you need to edit the DNS zone of the domain mydomain.com.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. But if I do that, what happens to the (now incorrect) A records in my example above, assuming that it's for a different domain (myotherdomain.com). Does Microsoft DNS automatically update those values?

Comment: The MS Dns do not update the values automatically. You need to update them.

Comment: Wow, so, excuse me going over this again, but if I change the IP address of my nameservers, then I must manually update every single domain that uses those nameservers to include the correct IP address? As far as I can tell from looking at zone file examples, these A records are not required, but MS DNS doesn't appear to provide a way of not including them!